# Firebase vulnerability in Realtime Database with access token from files

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

the project has files in **Storage** and data in **Realtime Database**. All of them have read access without any authentication. This is comfortable for users. For file access I use rest api:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/project_name.appspot.com/o/file_name.abc
```

Then I receive some data with TOKEN and create a new request to get the file directly:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/project_name.appspot.com/o/file_name.abc?token=<TOKEN>
```

Also I use firebase database in read mode with android sdk.

**But why the token from file access can be used to access the database?** This is madness, allowing to use the token from one type to another - files and database! I want provide database with small requests or via sdk. I just found that my database was easy downloaded in one request by somebody with token retrieved from the file:

```
https:/project_name.firebaseio.com/database/table_path.json?auth=<TOKEN>&format=export
```

I know about “Play Integrity” and it will be next step to protect.
I would be grateful for any ideas on how to protect the database, but the data should have read rights without authentication. I already use rules. How to restrict access to a token from a file for use with a database?

Comment: Did you try to edit the projects rules?

Comment: @AdamBasha Yes, I wrote that all the data has read access without authentication. Write access disabled. I don't understand why a token from file request can be used for a database. Looks like a firebase bug.